# Как создать wishlist?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Стоит задача сделать интеграцию готовой вёрстки магазина на woocommerce.
В вёрстке есть отдельная страница wishlist. Допустим при детальном просмотре есть кнопка добавить в корзину, и добавить в wishlist.
Подскажите, как организовать в магазине вывод страницы wishlist? Какой url должен быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение -  использовать плагин [YITH WooCommerce Wishlist](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/)
 или [аналогичные](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=WooCommerce%20Wishlist).

Comment: labris, а если без плагина, как это сделать?

Comment: Общая схема - продумать поля для таблицы в БД, если это будет в отдельной таблице, затем организовать обработку и вывод.

Comment: ну допустим продумал поля. Как теперь добавить новую страницу wishlist, какой url? И как сделать рабочую кнопку wishlist на странице детального просмотра?

Comment: @word а что, плагины религия не позволяет использовать? Тогда брать код плагина и запихивать его в тему, Что неправильно.

Comment: @labris позволяет или нет, это другой вопрос, не относящийся к теме

Comment: @word Здесь столько нюансов (к примеру, хранение вишлистов для каждого пользователя, их публикация в соцсетях и т.п.), что их описание и решения выходят за рамки возможного тут :)  По сути, плагин Вордпресса - это класс. Если надо использовать плагин в теме без установки плагина - то внедряем класс в тему, только зачем - такое решение гораздо менее гибкое.

Comment: соц. сети меня в данном случае не интересуют вообще, про них не было ни слова. Главное сделать основной функционал, а остальное я подпилю, что нужно

Comment: Тогда, опять-таки, самое простое - взять минимальный плагин для этого дела, посмотреть, как он устроен, и сделать под себя.